# How can I make a test a class that has in its __init__ the creation of a connection to a database?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class that creates a connection to a db (that needs to be alive for the purpose of the execution) and I would like to make Unit-testing of the class' methods (that don't use the connection).
How can I mock, or ignore the connection to the db?

```
from myutils import MyConnect
class Module:
    def __init__(self, payload):
        self.payload = payload
        format_date = "%Y-%m-%d"
        days = self.payload["days"]
        self.start_date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=days)).strftime(format_date)
        self.end_date = datetime.now().strftime(format_date)
        self.domain = self.payload["domain"]
        
        self.ms_connection = MyConnect(self.payload["MYSQL"]) # create connection to db
```

Comment: It is usually better if ``__init__`` receives the proper objects/values, not some generic mapping – that allows you to easily pass in the real connection in production and a fake connection in testing. You can offer an alternate constructor taking a mapping via a ``@classmethod`` easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding `MyConnect`, add the class used to create the connection as a parameter (whose default value can be hard-coded as `MyConnect`:

```
class Module:
    def __init__(self, payload, connecton_cls=MyConnect):
        self.payload = payload
        format_date = "%Y-%m-%d"
        days = self.payload["days"]
        self.start_date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=days)).strftime(format_date)
        self.end_date = datetime.now().strftime(format_date)
        self.domain = self.payload["domain"]
        
        self.ms_connection = connection_cls(self.payload["MYSQL"])
```

To test the method, you can pass whatever callable you like to create the mock connection.

```
def test_thing():
    m = Module(some_payload, Mock)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mocker and patch the object if you want to test some functions of this class.

```
myconnect = mocker.MagicMock(spec=MyConnect)

# Patch MyConnect so this will return mocker object of MyConnect class 
mocker.patch.object(mut, "MyConnect", return_value=myconnect) # module under test(mut
```